# Select element within React.js component not updating on first click in Firefox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

A select element within a React.js component takes 2 clicks to update in Firefox, but updates correctly on first click in Chrome and Safari.

It's a component using Redux + React-Redux and the value of the select element is dictated by a store value passed to it via mapStateToProps.

React Devtools shows the value of the select element updating correctly but the DOM itself doesn't update on the first click.

Redux Devtools is showing the correct actions being passed and correct state changes being made.

I've created a isolated recreation of the component tree in CodeSandbox (it functions correctly here so not a lot of help): https://codesandbox.io/s/jl7rpw3635

[Here's a gif of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5e49.gif)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't reproduce in Firefox 55.0.3 (64bit) / macOS 10.13.2 (17C88). Your codesandbox example works properly in my environment.

Comment: Yeah it works for me in CodeSandbox too, could be because CodeSandbox emulates the browser?

Comment: Can't reproduce the behaviour on windows either, is it doing the same if you remove `shouldComponentUpdate()` from `HourlyMinimumMinutes` ?

Comment: Also I've copied sandbox and run it locally. Can't reproduce again =)

Comment: @Dyo yeah it's still happening when I remove shouldComponentUpdate()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue by modifying the select component to render its options on mount, then attach them to a class property, avoiding re-rendering each option again every time the select component updates (they never change so it probably makes sense to do this) - https://codesandbox.io/s/m7m2qqp9py